# parsing bracketed things in ms sql

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse ms sql, which allows many things to be bracketed. For instance, you can bracket column names, table names, temp tables and data types.

This can take forms like the following:

```
select [#col1], [key], [case], [select], from [mytable]
CREATE TABLE MyTable ([MyCol] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

The problem I'm running into is that if I put a "bracketed identifier" into my lexer definition, then my parser will see tokens like [MyCol] and [varchar]. [varchar] isn't a data type that my parser knows about, but varchar is. My grammar can't handle the complexity of dealing with some bracketed tokens and some unbracketed tokens.

On the other hand, if I take the bracketing logic out of my lexer and put it into my parser, then I'm unable to parse column names that happen to contain sql keywords. ex:

```
select [key], [special case] from MyTable
```

If it matters, I'm generating c# code from this, not java code.

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing that in the parser is the best approach. In order to deal correctly with keywords as identifier you will have to add all allowed keywords to your parser identifier rule, similarly to what I have done in my [MySQL grammar](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/master/library/mysql.parser/grammar/MySQL.g#L3560).

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/tsql/tsql.g4) tsql grammar for ANTLR4. There is [`SQUARE_BRACKET_ID:  '[' ~']'+ ']';`](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/tsql/tsql.g4#L1341) and [rule id](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/tsql/tsql.g4#L912):

```
id
    : simple_id
    | DOUBLE_QUOTE_ID
    | SQUARE_BRACKET_ID
    ;
```

which can handle SQUARE_BRACKET_ID identifiers.